# PHP exec() is not working on Raspberry apache server

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi with an Apache server on it (PHP5). I got a code to control my relay module but PHP does not execute the python script.

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['LightON']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lighton_1.py");
}
if (isset($_POST['LightOFF']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lightoff_1.py");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<button class="btn" name="LightON">Light ON</button>&nbsp;
<button class="btn" name="LightOFF">Light OFF</button><br><br>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe you could add some of your config files, otherwise it is next to impossible to tell what your problem is

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `php.ini` if `exec()` is enabled. If it isn't, uncomment it and restart your PHP process (and maybe apache too)

EDIT:
After submitting an edit I noticed that you use `sudo` in your PHP `exec()` statement. This doesn't work if your root user is protected by a password (which it really should!).

Comment: Also, @user3726666 refrain from using pastebin-like links in your question, rather paste the code formatted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `shell_exec` command instead, it works for me and I have the same setup.

Comment: Note that I completely agree with Rob1NN - `sudo` cannot be used with `exec` or `shell_exec`.